# Where can I get intraday orderbook BTC/USD?

Tags: exchanges, raw-data, historical-trade-data

Where can I get intraday orderbook BTC/USD?

Hey there, I am searching for intraday orderbook BTC/USD of any exchange for at least one day. I have found that it's available only for some money. Is there possibility to get any for free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be it a stock exchange or a crypto one, it is kind of standard that the exchanges only show a portion of the orderbook and not the entire orderbook to the users.
You could possibly try crawling the exchange but that would still be futile since the orderbook displayed are sorted and only the top 20-30 entries. You won't get the entire data.
Bittrex has their set of [API's](https://bittrex.com/Home/Api) to retrieve exchange data, however that is not the intraday data. It updates timely. So you will  have to come up with a time based service which hits these API's on a regular time interval keeping in mind the hourly API usage limit and the activeness of the market.

Similarly a lot of the other exchanges also provide with API's which you can use to consolidate into one huge intraday order book.